# Return nested serializer in serializer method field

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a method field called `followers`. I get the list of followers in a `SerializerMethodField` :

```
followers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

I want to format the result with a specific serializer called `BaseUserSmallSerializer`. How should I implement the method `get_followers` to achieve that ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try this;

```
followers = BaseUserSmallSerializer(source='get_followers', many=True)
```

**OR**

You can use serializer inside methodfield;

```
def get_followers(self, obj):
   followers_queryset = #get queryset of followers
   return  BaseUserSmallSerializer(followers_queryset, many=True).data
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `followers` is not a property of my class BaseUser. I get : `Original exception text was: 'BaseUser' object has no attribute 'get_following'.`

Comment: ok, either you can write a model method or you can use BaseUserSmallSerializer inside serializerMethod field.

Comment: OK i got it. Thanks for the quick and complete answer. For the record, solution 2 is what I was looking for.

Comment: If you ever get your serializer is not json serializable error, you probably did not did call data property on the serializer.
`BaseUserSmallSerializer(followers_queryset, many=True).data`

Comment: @Geo Jacob God bless you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a more **generic solution**:

**SerializerMethodNestedSerializer** which works same as serializers.**SerializerMethodField** but wraps the result with the passed serializer and returns a **dict**

```
class SerializerMethodNestedSerializer(serializers.SerializerMethodField):
    """Returns nested serializer in serializer method field"""

    def __init__(self, kls, kls_kwargs=None, **kwargs):
        self.kls = kls
        self.kls_kwargs = kls_kwargs or {}
        super(SerializerMethodNestedSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        repr_value = super(SerializerMethodNestedSerializer, self).to_representation(value)
        if repr_value is not None:
            return self.kls(repr_value, **self.kls_kwargs).data
```

**Usage**

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    payment_method = SerializerMethodNestedSerializer(kls=PaymentCardSerializer)

    def get_payment_method(self, obj):
        return PaymentCard.objects.filter(user=obj.user, active=True).first()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("payment_method",)
```

```
class PaymentCardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('date_created', 'provider', 'external_id',)
        model = PaymentCard
```

The **expected output** of `SerializerMethodNestedSerializer(kls=PaymentCardSerializer)`

```
None or {'date_created': '2020-08-31', 'provider': 4, 'external_id': '123'}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't pass the serializer context through correctly.